# Faraday Gem Update locked because of Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, rubygems, faraday

I was trying to update Faraday Gem to 0.12.0.

However, I ended up being as same since oauth2 gem has a dependency on Faraday
(<0.10, >=0.8) [It says bundler has locked Faraday at 0.9.0]

The "gem A" I wanted to install requires Faraday with version 0.12.

How am I going to install 0.12.0 Faraday so that I can install "gem A" and also leave Oauth2 working?

How does the decision normally get made when it comes to the gem dependency issue?
(If it had not been limited by inequality, then things would have been straight forward though, but nothing I can help on the gem creation )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FaradayMiddleware::OAuth2Refresh](https://github.com/grokify/faraday_middleware-oauth2_refresh) and install the gem:

```
gem 'faraday_middleware-oauth2_refresh'
```